# Change font color of one menu item

Tags: wordpress, navigationbar, twenty-ten-theme

I am customizing the WordPress twentyten them and am trying to change the font color of only one menu item. I would greatly appreciate it if someone could point me in the right direction.

I have tried the following change to the child theme style.css with no success:

```
#menu-item-35{ font-color:#F2CE52; }
```

Comment: PAt, for background color use background:#F00; color: is for text color, try .menu li:first-child a{color:'color what you need'}

Answer (score 0):

You must to use pseudo class :first-child

For example:

```
*{color:#fff;}

.menu li:first-child{
color:#000;
}
```

Info about this pseudo class:

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_firstchild.asp

Comment: I appreciate your feedback Makc! However, that pertains to the background color. Im looking to change the text color of just 1 of the menu items. All of them are gray and I need just 1 of the text links yellow.

Comment: PAt, for background color use background:#F00; color: is for text color, try .menu li:first-child a{color:'color what you need'}

Comment: But thats not what I am looking for. I DONT want the background color... I want to change the TEXT color. I have no background color. I just need to style the one menu id. Font color and margin.

Comment: Heres my 50th or so shot at this and I still can't get it to work!!

'#menu-item-35 {
 color: #29415A !important;
        margin-left: 5px !important;
}'

I am pulling my hair out trying to find anyone with and example and am falling short!!

Please help!!